# At how many points is this function continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Question: 
Let $f$ be a function with domain $[-1, 1]$ such that the coordinates of each point $(x,y)$ satisfy $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. What is the total number of points at which f is necessarily continuous?

My Answer:
I think the answer should be zero. Here's why: the graph may just be a bunch of discrete points lying on the unit circle. At each of these points, the graph is discontinuous. However, the correct answer is 2. Can someone explain where I am wrong?

Comment: Please tell us what *whatever* is in $f\colon[-1,1]\to\mathit{whatever}$.  Thank you.

Comment: What does the graph look like near $x=1$ and $x=-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know *something* about the function's behavior, since $y^2 = 1 - x^2$, we have $y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$, and the 'worst' it could be is if it jumps between the positive and negative square roots a lot. That is, if $x$ changes a little, then $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ (the positive root) only changes a little, and the only way to make this discontinuous is by jumping to the other root.

I think we could construct this worst-case behavior by doing something like 'take the positive root if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, negative root if irrational.'

So, with that in mind, what are the points $x$ where choosing the positive vs. the negative root doesn't make that much difference?

Comment: Aah yes, it should be $x= -1,1$. Thanks for explaining it so well!

Comment: You're welcome!